# Powershell calling function with parameter inside if statement

Tags: function, powershell, if-statement, parameters

I've wrote a function like this:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,
    ParameterSetName="Error")]
    [String[]]
    $ErrorName
    )

function Get-Err
{
if ($ErrorName -eq "SyncCert KO @vLDSA") {
    "do something"
    }
elseif ($ErrorName -eq "SyncCert KO @vLDS0") {
    "do something"
    }
elseif ($ErrorName -eq "SyncCert KO @vLDS1") {
    "do something"
    }
elseif ($ErrorName -eq $null) {
    "You must enter a parameter to start the script, preceded by the prefix '-Error'!"
    }

elseif ($ErrorName -eq 0) {
    "You must enter a parameter to start the script, preceded by the prefix '-Error'!"
    }

else {"Unexpected value '$ErrorName'"}
}
```

and I want to call it like that:

```
$a = "foo"
if ($a) {Get-Err -Error "SyncCert KO @vLDSA"} else {"bar"}
```

Unfortunately wont't works!

Shell matchs else condition and says "Unexpected value ''"

PSDebug is not clear for me:

```
DEBUG:    1+ if ( >>>> $a) { Get-Err -Error "SyncCert KO @vLDSA"} else {"bar"}
DEBUG:     ! CALL function '<ScriptBlock>'
DEBUG:    1+ if ($a) {  >>>> Get-Err -Error "SyncCert KO @vLDSA"} else {"bar"}
DEBUG:   16+  >>>> {
DEBUG:     ! CALL function 'script:Get-Err'  (defined in file 'E:\Scripts\functions.ps1')
DEBUG:   17+ if ( >>>> $ErrorName -eq "SyncCert KO @vLDSA") {
DEBUG:   20+ elseif ( >>>> $ErrorName -eq "SyncCert KO @vLDS0") {
DEBUG:   23+ elseif ( >>>> $ErrorName -eq "SyncCert KO @vLDS1") {
DEBUG:   41+ else { >>>> "Unexpected value ''"}
```

Seems that "ErrorName" is not interpreted at commandline

If I take off the function sintax, in "script mode" works...

Can Someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the parameter in the function itself:

```bsh
function Get-Err
{
    param($ErrorName)

    # ...
}
```

Now we can also move a lot of input validation to the param block and simplify the code:

```bsh
function Get-Err
{
    param(
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$ErrorName
    )

    if ($ErrorName -eq "SyncCert KO @vLDSA") {
        "do something"
    }
    elseif ($ErrorName -eq "SyncCert KO @vLDS0") {
        "do something"
    }
    elseif ($ErrorName -eq "SyncCert KO @vLDS1") {
        "do something"
    }
    else {
      "Unexpected value '$ErrorName'"
    }
}
```